# How to fix "Image (loaded by stb_image) takes up too much memory"

Tags: c++, image, loading, stb-image

I am currently learning cg, and I have to load some textures. I tried using stb_images and it works fine but when i load an image inside the memory it takes up too much space.

I am using a small jpg(512*512, 154kb), but if I load it 10 times, it will occupy around 12 MB of memory.
(I use visual studio diagnostic tool to check process memory)

How could I eliminate this wast amount of memory usage.

```
struct Image {
    int width, height, bpp;
    unsigned char* rgba;

    Image(const std::string& filePath) {
        rgba = stbi_load(filePath.c_str(), &width, &height, &bpp, 4);
    }

    ~Image() {
        stbi_image_free(rgba);
    }
};

std::vector<Image> images;
images.reserve(10);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    images.emplace_back("res/textures/image.jpg");
```

Comment: It occupies around 12MB

Comment: Blush. I misread by just one tinsy order of magnitude... :-)